# Google Vision API detects right characters from a language but shows a different language as detected

Tags: c#, json, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to get Google Vision API to detect the Language "*Dhivehi*" (languageHints Code '*dv*') which is Listed under [Experimental Languages](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages#experimental-langs) in their OCR Language Support page.

Despite the service detecting characters from the language (characters only unique to the language) there isn't a single detection of "*dv*" in the JSON result. Adding or removing the Language hints doesn't seem to affect the results.

In addition, from the JSON result, the `detectedLanguages` property only shows "*en*" with very low confidence

```
"property": {
    "detectedLanguages": [
        {
            "languageCode": "en",
            "confidence": 0.11
        }
     ],
     "detectedBreak": null
},
```

Second attempt showed a confidence score of 0.12. So its consistently low.

This is my current implementation of the API (only the relevant part included)

```
 // ...paths   

 Feature feature = new Feature
 {
    Type = Feature.Types.Type.DocumentTextDetection
 };

 // create an imageContext class and add the languageHints code to it
 var imageContext = new ImageContext();
 imageContext.LanguageHints.Add("dv");

 // inputConfig and outputConfig are defined above
 var asyncRequest = new AsyncAnnotateFileRequest() { InputConfig = inputConfig, OutputConfig = outputConfig, ImageContext = imageContext };
 asyncRequest.Features.Add(feature);

  // create and execute requests
 List<AsyncAnnotateFileRequest> requests = new List<AsyncAnnotateFileRequest>();
 requests.Add(asyncRequest);

 var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
 var operation = client.AsyncBatchAnnotateFiles(requests);

 operation.PollUntilCompleted();
```

This behavior seems like a bug but posting here to be sure I haven't missed out anything